# Grails GORM: Updating an assoicated object's property on beforeUpdate not persisted

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a domain class like:

```
class X {
    String name

    Y y 

    def beforeUpdate() {
        y.name = "new name"
        y.save() //DOESN'T work, adding flush: true throws exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeUpdate` event occurs during the flush, so you cannot trigger another flush. (If you do, you will get a stack overflow.)

If the `beforeUpdate` returns false, it will cancel the save. I suggest you try the following:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    y.name = "new name"
    return true
}
```

I believe that the save method is returning null (failure), which is coerced to false.

Comment: This worked! Previously the instance of `X` was being saved but not `Y`'s. Why did this make `y` to be saved?

Comment: GORM will cascade the saving of embedded objects by default. I can only guess why it was not saved before.

Comment: Is this a way to circumvent the validation of the depending domain object?
I.e. is it possible to set an invalid value without knowing it?

Comment: @StefanRother-Stübs can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I'am not sure, when the validation of a depending domain object happens but if  `beforeUpdate()` happens after all validation steps then it might be possible to set a value that would otherwise be rejected by the validation

Comment: I don't think so, beforeInsert and beforeUpdate are supposed to be called before the validation.